# How to use set of temperatures values to predict the status of an equipment in a smart home with HMM

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, prediction

Good morning ,

I have a data set of temperatures values during a whole day ( about 45 values ) and I want to evaluate the status of a air conditioner whether is on /off compared to those temperatures values on that day .

I would like to use the HMM toolbox in matlab in order to predict the air conditioner status ( on/ off ) during one day and I confused how to proceed in the situation of training and predicting process with hidden Markov models.

I WOULD like to know and identify the transition matrix , the observation matrix , the sequence of observation and the prior probability of this kind of hmm and what training data should I insert into it ?

```
% chaincode data set for class ‘1’
data1{1} = [%values of temperatures in one day%];
data1{2} = [%values of temperatures in one day% ];
data1{3} = [%values of temperatures in one day%];
% HMM for class '0' and random initialization of parameters
hmm0.prior = [1 0 0 0 0];
hmm0.transmat = rand(5,5); 
% 3 by 3 transition matrix
hmm0.transmat(2,1) =0; hmm0.transmat(3,1) = 0; hmm0.transmat(3,2) = 0;
hmm0.transmat = mk_stochastic(hmm0.transmat);

hmm0.obsmat = rand(5, 16); 
% # of states * # of observation
hmm0.obsmat = mk_stochastic(hmm0.obsmat) ;

% HMM for class '1' and random initialiation of parameters
hmm1.prior = [1 0 ];
hmm1.transmat = rand(2,2);
% 2 by 2 transition matrix
hmm1.transmat(2,1) =0;
hmm1.transmat = mk_stochastic(hmm1.transmat);
hmm1.transmat
hmm1.obsmat = rand(2, 40); 
% # of states * # of observation
hmm1.obsmat = mk_stochastic(hmm1.obsmat) ;
% Training of HMM model 0 (Baum-Welch algorithm)
[LL0, hmm0.prior, hmm0.transmat, hmm0.obsmat] = dhmm_em(data0, hmm0.prior,hmm0.transmat, hmm0.obsmat) ;
% smoothing of HMM observation parameter: set floor value 1.0e-5
hmm0.obsmat = max(hmm0.obsmat, 1.0e-5);
% Training of HMM model 1 (Baum-Welch algorithm)
[LL1, hmm1.prior, hmm1.transmat, hmm1.obsmat] = dhmm_em(data1, hmm1.prior,hmm1.transmat, hmm1.obsmat) ;
% smoothing of HMM observation parameter: set floor value 1.0e-5
hmm1.obsmat = max(hmm1.obsmat, 1.0e-5);
```

Comment: This is a statement of intent. What have you actually done, and do you have a specific question?

Comment: I edited the question and added some code ... the last sentence is my question ... thank you in advance